# Main Winforms application window appears in background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

maybe someone can explain this extrange behaviour.

When I develop a Winforms application in C# and then I build and run by double clicking on the exe file, the main window appears in background. To get it to foreground I have to click on the taskbar icon.

The strange thing is that if I have a second monitor, and browse the folders inside the extended screen and then double click on the exe file, the main window appears in the main monitor.

And to finish the curiosities, if I run the application inside Visual Studio, main windows appears immediately as it should be.

This is the main method in Program.cs file:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
```

The "if" statement does not execute since there is no other instance running.

To try to force the window to be shown in front of the others, I override WndProc method but it did not work:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == ControlVisitas.Helpers.SingleInstance.WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE)
        {
            ControlVisitas.Helpers.WinApi.ShowToFront(this.Handle);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You did not post the most important code.  [Do not reinvent the wheel](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Comment: I did not reinvent the wheel... I use a library I've found Googleing, similar to the one you posted.... however, that is not the problem. Please post a most useful comment. Thanks

Comment: It is built into the .NET Framework.  Library?  Well, not useful either I guess.

Comment: Forget about single instance library and concentrate on the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The `if` statement is not irrelevant: you always call `Helpers.SingleInstance.Start`.

Comment: I have deleted the if statement

Comment: Process of elimination: see what happens if you change to `Application.Run(new Form());`

Comment: I have solved the problem. The problem was with Splash Screen. I have added an Activate() method call of the main form just before the Splash Screen window is actually disposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a Splash Screen.

I have just put main form activate Method before actually closing the splash screen.